# Laravel and Azure Error: Internal Server Error

Tags: php, laravel, azure, laravel-5, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an App Service on Microsoft Azure that uses Laravel 5.2 and PHP 7. The problem that I have is that sometimes while I'm browsing the site I get the error:

> this page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred

This happens randomly but when it happens it blocks the route, for example I'm browsing without problems the address http://elsitio.com/details/12 then I click again and it throws the error.

To get rid of the error I have to restart the App Service and it will work fine so I think that it has something to do with the Views Cache in the app.

Aside from setting the Laravel `.env` I haven't done any configurations.

Using phpinfo I found that the site appears to be running on FastCGI, but I'm not really sure about that, since the error shown appears to be managed by IIS.

**My questions are:**

> 1. Any ideas on what may be causing the problem?
> 2. How can I restart FastCGI/IIS service without restarting the App Service, for example in Apache over Linux would be `service httpd
>      restart`.

**UPDATE 1**

It's a very strange error, sometimes I get the error that some componentes are missing: `Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\QueueableCollection' not found` then I do `$: composer install` and it starts to work, then I reload the page and I get another error related to a missing component.

If I change the PHP version it starts to work again :(.

Comment: it seams that you have set in your env file `APP_DEBUG = false` and you can't see the actual error. Also it would be good to add your `.env` in the question (without information about database connection)

Comment: APP_DEBUG is set to true :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you get a 500 http error, it means that you may occur a php fatal error. You can enable the display errors configuration to diagnosis the error. Meanwhile, considering you are facing a randomly issue, you can also enable the error log, for tracing the issue.

You can refer to [Info About PHP Fatal Error and Error Log on Azure Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/04/15/info-about-php-fatal-error-and-error-log-on-azure-website/) for more info. Also you can refer to [How to: Change the built-in PHP configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations).

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: It's a very strange error, sometimes I get that certain elements of Laravel are missing: `Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\QueueableCollection' not found` then I do $: composer install and it starts to work, then again it works, then I reload the page and I get another error. If I change the PHP version it starts to work again :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem when migrating to Azure that Composer wouldn't pull certain files when I ran `composer install`. Try downloading the file manually  [from here](https://github.com/illuminate/contracts/tree/master/Queue) and run `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is done correctly, just do the following.

1. Create a `web.conf` under `public`.
2. Copy the code below.

   ```
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
         <rules>
           <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
             <conditions>
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
           </rule>
           <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
             <conditions>
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
           </rule>
         </rules>
       </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```